# Language Translation using multiple values sending and receiving at a time using php

Tags: php

How to send multiple values at a time for translating other than single value. I have tried below code for single value translation. But I need multiple values sending and receiving at a time.

Please help me

Thank you!

Your previous code:

**function translate($q, $sl, $tl){
$res= file_get_contents("https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&dt=bd&dt=ex&dt=ld&dt=md&dt=qca&dt=rw&dt=rm&dt=ss&dt=t&dt=at&sl=".$sl."&tl=".$tl."&hl=hl&q=".urlencode($q), $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/transes.html");
$res=json_decode($res);
return $res[0][0][0];
}**

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. please take a moment and read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask about how to asking questions also read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example about how to ask a good question with minimum requirement.

Comment: please share your workout, code snippets, and any useful information to help others answer your question.